# compare 2 array of objects. match by ids, push object property into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash, linq.js

I have 2 arrays. users and posts. posts contain a property "post_by" which is the id of one of the users. I need to match the user and push the first & last name into the post object as a new property. Goal is I need to display the name of the user that made the post in a table.

note* I can use javascript, jquery, linq.js or lodash.

fiddle with json
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zy5oe25n/5/)

```
var users = [
    {
        "id": "15e640c1-a481-4997-96a7-be2d7b3fcabb",
        "first_name": "Kul",
        "last_name": "Srivastva",
    },
    {
        "id": "4cada7f0-b961-422d-8cfe-4e96c1fc11dd",
        "first_name": "Rudy",
        "last_name": "Sanchez",
    },
    {
        "id": "636f9c2a-9e19-44e2-be88-9dc71d705322",
        "first_name": "Todd",
        "last_name": "Brothers"
    },
    {
        "id": "79823c6d-de52-4464-aa7e-a15949fb25fb",
        "first_name": "Mike",
        "last_name": "Piehota"
    },
    {
        "id": "e2ecd88e-c616-499c-8087-f7315c9bf470",
        "first_name": "Nick",
        "last_name": "Broadhurst"
    }
    ]

    var posts = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "status": "Active",
        "post_title": "test title",
        "post_body": "test body",
        "post_by": "4cada7f0-b961-422d-8cfe-4e96c1fc11dd"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "status": "Fixed",
        "post_title": "test title two",
        "post_body": "test body two",
        "post_by": "79823c6d-de52-4464-aa7e-a15949fb25fb"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/zy5oe25n/7/

```
console.log($.map(posts, function(post){
  var user = $.grep(users, function(user){
    return user.id === post.post_by;
  })[0];

  post.first_name = user.first_name;
  post.last_name = user.last_name;
  return post;
}));
```

Comment: sorry, should have been more clear. i need the user first and last name pushed into the post object

Comment: Oh, your wanting to merge?

Comment: You're mutating the data, you shouldn't use `map()`, `each()` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a lodash approach:

```
_.map(posts, function(item) {
    return _.assign(
        _.pick(_.find(users, { id: item.post_by }),
            'first_name', 'last_name'),
        item
    );
});
```

It's using [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) to map the posts array to a new array of new objects (immutable data). It's then using [find()](https://lodash.com/docs#find) to locate the user object, and uses [pick()](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) to get the properties we need. Finally, [assign()](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) adds the post properties to the new object that `pick()` created.

Answer (score 1):

For good measure, using linq.js.

```
var userMap = Enumerable.From(users).ToObject("$.id");
posts.forEach(function (post) {
    var user = userMap[post.post_by];
    if (user) {
        post.first_name = user.first_name;
        post.last_name = user.last_name;
    }
});
```

Note, we're using the builtin `forEach()` for arrays, linq.js is not needed for that part.